# I need an example PowerShell script for deploying the MS virtual assistant template

Tags: powershell, deployment, botframework, bots

I'm new to the framework and PowerShell. I'm trying to deploy the virtual assistant via PowerShell but I can't auto-create an AD app. I can't work out what the PowerShell script should look like in order to add an app ID and secret in manually. Can anyone help with an example?

This is the documentation: https://github.com/microsoft/AI/blob/master/docs/tutorials/assistantandskilldeploymentsteps.md

But I just can't work out what the script should look like - I'm not given an option to enter the app ID and secret when I run `.\deployment\scripts\deploy.ps1`.

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. Show the code you have so far and explain (as detailed as possible) what both the expected and the actual behavior of that code are.

Comment: great .. thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the file, `.\deployment\scripts\deploy.ps1`, you can see that the first lines are:

```bsh
Param(
    [string] $name,
    [string] $resourceGroup,
    [string] $location,
    [string] $appId,
    [string] $appPassword,
    [string] $luisAuthoringKey,
    [string] $luisAuthoringRegion,
    [string] $parametersFile,
    [string] $languages = "en-us",
    [string] $outFolder = $(Get-Location),
    [string] $logFile = $(Join-Path $PSScriptRoot .. "deploy_log.txt")
)
```

This means that the command accepts all of those parameters. So, you can specify `appId` and `appPassword` by calling the command with:

`.\Deployment\Scripts\deploy.ps1 --appId "<yourAppId>" --appPassword "<yourAppPassword>"`

Comment: Single dash not double dash. 
.\Deployment\Scripts\deploy.ps1 -appId "<yourAppId>" -appPassword "<yourAppPassword>"